# Could not toggle nav items and icon

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning vanilla javascript and i wanted to implement the nav features similar to http://www.startupturkey.com/ when hamburger icon is clicked. I tried but could not toggle the hamburger icon to remove icon when clicked and vice versa along with the nav items to show like in the reference link. What i tried is get the value of attribute class of icon and change it to remove if value is content and vice versa. I have created a fiddle too and here is the link of it

https://jsfiddle.net/0taywkL5/

Also here is my code

```
<header class="header">
      <!-- <i class="reorder icon"></i> -->
      <a href="#" class="header__logo">LOGO</a>
      <i class="content icon header-icon" style="float: right;"></i>
      <div class="ui vertical menu" style="display:none;">
        <a class="active teal item">
          Blog
        </a>
        <a class="item">
          Discussion
        </a>
        <a class="item">
          Features
        </a>
        <a class="item">
          Team
        </a>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section class="home-header show">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="request-invitation">
        <h2>REQUEST AN INVITATION</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="connyct-short-intro">
        <h1>HEADING IN THE MIDDLE OF IMAGE</h1>
      </div>
    </section>


document.querySelector('.header-icon').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var value = this.getAttribute('class');
   if (value === "content"){
     console.log('yes content');
     this.classList.remove('content');
     this.classList.add('remove');
   } else {
     this.classList.remove('remove');
     this.classList.add('content');
   }
    var verticalMenu = document.querySelector('.vertical');
    verticalMenu.style.display = 'block';
});
```

I don't want to jump to jquery. Can anyone please help me with the vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I could do this but if anyone has suggestion on code improvement please do suggest me

```
document.querySelector('.header-icon').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var value = this.getAttribute('class');
   if (this.className === "icon header-icon content"){
     console.log('yes content');
     this.classList.remove('content');
     this.classList.add('remove');
   } else {
     this.classList.remove('remove');
     this.classList.add('content');
   }
    var verticalMenu = document.querySelector('.vertical');
    verticalMenu.style.display = verticalMenu.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought that simple in http://www.startupturkey.com/ is using a `div` to cover the menu burger icon, and when you toggle the burger icon, the `div` fade out but not remove the burger icon (you can check out with development tool `F12`).

As your fiddle, I edited another version with this effect for you(but not that pretty XDD)

https://jsfiddle.net/GeorgioWan/0taywkL5/1/

> p.s. Animation by [Animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css)